# Java + Jersey- sending utf-8 encoded data

Tags: java, encoding, jersey

In my application I need to use the rest api of a web service. For now I need to send an xml message. The problem is, some of the characters in this xml are polish diacritics. Now, the code of my message sending looks like this

```
WebResource r = client.resource(resourceAddress);
String response = r.accept(
        MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_TYPE,
        MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE,
        MediaType.TEXT_HTML_TYPE
    )
    .type(MediaType.TEXT_XML_TYPE)
    .header("Authorization", authorizationString)
    .post(String.class, event);
```

Java Strings are UTF-16 and my XML should be UTF-8 encoded. Is there a way to tell Jersey to change somehow the encoding before serialization? Or maybe there is some other way, so I can send this String data as UTF-8 and not UTF-16 using Jersey client api?

Comment: The fact that Java stores strings internally as UTF-16 has nothing to do with it.

Comment: Are you sure? I think it has, because the object is serialized and then send through the net, so UTF-16 representation is sent.

Comment: The data is serialized to XML, which is a string format, not a binary one. That means it still has an encoding which is not necessarily the same as the language's internal representation.

Comment: Even so, at the basic level there are bytes send that are interpreted in the specific way and I think, that because java strings are utf-16 in the memory, the bytes that are sent are the utf-16 and not utf-8 bytes.